# Query and Display Results Every 'X' amount of Minutes from Oracle Database

Tags: php, python, xml, oracle, plsql

Is there a way that I can query an Oracle 10g database, and display the results in a dynamically refreshed html file every 3 minutes, for example?

Here is my predicament: I have several queries that I would LOVE to display the results of to a whole organization on a basic HTML web page with some CSS.  The problem is that I do NOT want a user to be able to constantly refresh a page in his/her browser, and thus severely bog down the database.  I have no problem writing the queries, or writing the HTML and CSS needed to display the tables.  It's almost as if I would like to query, export results to XML every 3 minutes, and constantly have an HTML or PHP file that is pointing to the dynamically updated XML file.  I am open to other options as well...

I have basic user access with the Oracle DB...nothing Admin like.  I do have access to a server, though, and have experience with PHP, PL/SQL, and HTML.  Perhaps I would have to get into a lower level programming language like Python?  I am kind of stuck here.  Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

you can also execute an Ajax Request every 3 minutes using the setTimeout() function.

Using jQuery framework

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout("getFeed()", 180000); //180000 = 3 minutes in milliseconds
});

function getFeed() {
    //ajaxRequest here
}
```

For more info on ajax you can go here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Setup a [materialized view](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm)(mv), point your app to this mv, and then setup a scheduler job to refresh it on whatever frequency you like.

See [dbms_scheduler](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm) for setting up scheduler jobs in Oracle.

One note: you may want to do an atomic_refresh=>true to do deletes/inserts into the mv instead of truncate/insert (if atomic_refresh=>false, there will be 0 rows in mv until refresh is completed).

An simple example mv creation:

```
create materialized view MY_MV
tablespace MY_TS
build immediate
refresh complete on demand
with primary key
as
SELECT a.foo, b.bar
from table_a a, table_b b
where a.col1 = b.col2
and a.baz='BLAH'
;
```

An example refresh call:

```
dbms_mview.refresh('MY_MV', 'C', atomic_refresh=>true);
```